# How to replace one left character from a string?

Tags: php

This is my simple code:

```
$string = "PAAUSTRALIA" ;
$output = str_replace("A","",$string);    
$output = str_replace("P","",$output);
```

Here output is: USTRLI

But, my desired output is AUSTRALIA.

Is there any easy way in php to do this task? Simply, I want to replace one character each time from the left side of the string for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a function to do this task smoothly. Please have a look at my code:

```
<?php
function onereplace($str,$replaced_character){
$spt = str_split($str,1);
for($i=0; $i <= (count($spt) - 1) ; $i++){
 if($spt[$i] == $replaced_character){
   unset($spt[$i]);
   break;
 }
}

return implode('',$spt);
}


$string = "PAAUSTRALIA" ;
$string = onereplace($string,"P");
echo $string = onereplace($string,"A");

?>
```

Hope it will help you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try [substr](http://php.net/substr) along with [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) instead of [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) as

```
$string = "PAAUSTRALIA" ;
$string = substr($string,(strpos($string, 'P') > -1));
$string = substr($string,(strpos($string, 'A') > -1));
echo $string; //AUSTRALIA
```

Edited

Making a function will also do the same as

```
echo removeOne($string,'p');
function removeOne($str,$value){
     return substr($str,(stripos($str,$value) > -1));
}
```

[str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) will find the occurrence of letter 'A' within string and replace it to `''`

Answer (score 1):

Another Option would be to use `preg_replace` which supports a limit-parameter:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
$string = "PAAUSTRALIA" ;
$string = preg_replace("@A@", "", $string, 1);
$string = preg_replace("@P@", "", $string, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this function in php for your task: `substr(yourstring, startindex, endindex)`

**Edited**

`substr(yourstring, 0, strlen($yourstring))` 
For manual refer this link:http://php.net/substr

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to do it dynamically. So, how can I get dynamic startindex and endindex ?

Comment: @AdamSmith, what is your requirement for your startindex i am not clear from your question but if you want to do it from the start i.e 0 then you just have 0 as your startindex and length of the string as endindex. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr($string ,1,strlen($string));
```

Reference:

```
substr(string,start,length)
```

Answer (score 0):

str_replace will replace all the characters matched in a string.

Try to use substr()

```
$string = "AAUSTRALIA" ;
$output = substr($string, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove 1 char at the time from the left then all you need is substr():

```
$string = "PAAUSTRALIA" ;
$string = substr($string, 1); // AAUSTRALIA
$string = substr($string, 1); // AUSTRALIA
```